# Position div below another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a `div` layer as shown in this picture:

[image]

When the user clicks on the Site List button, I want the `div` to appear over the form. So far, I used the toggle function from jQuery to hide and show the `div` (not sure if its the best way). I need help positioning the `div` as shown in the picture. How can I achieve this?
Also when the user selects a particular site, I want it to load that specific site's information in the form below. Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: Please post the code in a snippet ([See illustration](http://i.imgur.com/p94EZRA.png?1)), [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), [PenCode.io](http://pencode.io), or [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co)

In addition, you should refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: That looks similar to what you can do with JQuery UI Dialog.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the fiddle earlier. The div im trying to display is at the bottom. When the user selects a site, I want it to hide the div and populate the fields in the form. 

https://jsfiddle.net/bobejgnq/3/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `position: absolute` on the table itself and do the following:

1) to center the table vertically, you have to define height.
  2) the table has to be a child of `#site-level-ext-lighting-form` so you need to modify the html slightly.
  3) you have to specify `position: relative` on the parent element.

```
#my-sites-select-layer{
  width:900px;
  height: 250px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I modified your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mzebct1/).

Answer (score 0):

you must use `position: absolute` 
Please visit this link  [CSS Layout - The position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) to find out more about the positions

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question is how to position that table like the image you provided.

I corrected the `<select>`s, the majority of them had the same `id: exterior-location`. Under no circumstances should you ever have more than one `id` on the same page sharing the same value, `id`s **must be unique**.

The `<form>` is wrapped around everything.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/2qyfpnzg/embedded/result/)

Relevant CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* Core CSS */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.45 Verdana;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: #EDF;
  color: #221;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* modal */

#my-sites-select-layer {
  position: absolute;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
  top: 75px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 4444;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
  padding: 22px 40px 50px 0;
}

#site-select-table {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```